# Sorting the vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors in matlab:

```
x=[2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
y=[1, 5, 1, 5, 5]
Q=[7, 8, 4, 6, 8]
```

The modified vectors should be

```
x=[2, 3]
y=[1, 5]
Q=[12, 22 ]
```

Here x,y represents coordinates and Q a value depending upon (x,y).

The coordinates are getting repeated, like (2,1)  has come twice, then I need to modify the vectors x and y representing unique coordinates and summing the values of Q for the particular coordinates e.g. (2,1) has come twice and the values of Q at those coordinates are 7 and 5 then for modified vectors coordinate (2,1) has to come once and corresponding `Q value 7+5=12` and similarly for `(3,5) Q is 8+6+8=22`.

Comment: You mean `7+4=11` right? Where does your `5` come from? I'm assuming this is a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[XY, ~, ic] = unique([x' y'],'rows')
xu = XY(:,1).'; % The unique x you want
yu = XY(:,2).'; % The unique y you want
Qu = accumarray(ic,Q').';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!!